# React: Flow: Import a local js file - cannot resolve issue module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, flowtype, flow-typed

I am using [Flow: Static type checking library](https://reactjs.org/docs/static-type-checking.html) for react front end application, it throws "cannot resolve" for internal imports from src directory:

```
Example in file at path: src/abc/def/ghi/hello.jsx, I am using the following import:
import words from '../words';

--> Throws error "Cannot resolve module ../words

words.js is in src/abc/def dir
```

**EDITED:** 
My .flowconfig looks like this after I installed flow-typed:

```
[ignore]
.*/node_modules/.*
.*/build/.*
.*/dist/.*


[include]
.*/src/.*
.*/test/.*

[libs]
flow-typed

[lints]

[options]
all=true
module.system.node.resolve_dirname=node_modules
module.system.node.resolve_dirname=src

[strict]
```

How do I map flow for such imports in .flowconfig file ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `import {words}`

Comment: Sorry, { words } doesn't seem to work. Still shows the same error.

Comment: flow didn't support relative path yet.
you should use complete path to fix this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it working.

Relative paths don't really work with Flow.

We need to map imports from Project root for Flow to understand.

I changed my import to

```
import words from 'def/words';
```

Add the following to your .flowconfig file

```
module.name_mapper='^def\(.*\)$' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/src/abc/def/\1'
```

Fixes above error.

Answer (score 3):

To get to ./def from ./hello.jsx, you have to go up another directory

import words from '../../words';

Comment: I don't think so, when I hover click the '../words' it takes to the right file not when I mention '../../words', and the import worked perfectly fine and app runs fine too, its just after I started to use FLOW for static type checking, it has something to do with name_mapper in FLOW which I am unable to configure in .flowconfig.

Comment: hmm, try module.system=haste

https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#toc-module-system-node-haste

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work. Haste is mostly for react-native and also read that it is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

```
/path/to/project/node_modules/.bin/flow stop
/path/to/project/yarn run flow (or your flow invoking script)
```

this fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case problem was that I use relative paths with webpack e.g

```
resolve: {
    modules: [
         path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
         ...
    ]
}
```

So, I can import my custom module from src like that (without write src/)

```
import CustomModule from 'pages/CustomModule'
```

But flow doesnt now about that webpack config, so I must add in my .flowconfig file next code

```
[options]
module.name_mapper='src' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/src'
```

More info

[about flow options](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/)

[about name_mapper](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#toc-module-name-mapper-regex-string)